# Is there some feature like C# "using" in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way I can make it easier to call my alert in the typescript code below. Here's where my alert is coded:

```
module Admin.Shared.Alerts {
    export class alerts {
        static mvcOnFailure(message: string) {
            dialog.alertWin("Internal Application Error", message);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a small snippet example of where I call it:

```
module Admin.MyAccount.Access {
    export function ajaxDone(data: string, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) {       
        Admin.Shared.Alerts.alerts.mvcOnFailure("x");
    }

}
```

The problem is that there is such a long string to call the alert. Is there some way that I can do something like a "using" in C# where I don't have to specify "Admin.Shared.Alerts" ?

Comment: Sure: `var Alerts = Admin.Shared.Alerts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two recommendations for you in this respect. The first is that you reconsider your module structure. As soon as you see namespaces such as "Common", "Shared" or "Core" it tells you there is a problem, because these are not words that describe what the code inside is likely to do. Good names are "Messaging", "Alerts", "Payments" - you can tell straight away what kind of stuff you will find there.

So recommendation number 1 is to remove the "Shared" namespace.

```
module Admin.Alerts {
```

If you are building a large TypeScript program, you may want to follow the module patterns that are commonly used in CommonJS application. You use simple module names but nest them in folders:

*.\Admin\Alerts.ts*

```
module Alerts {
```

You would import the module using

```
import alerts = module('.\Admin\Alerts.ts');
```

And then use it in your code under the `alerts` name.

In a web app, you would use a module loader, such as requires.js to handle all the loading for you so it wouldn't be much additional work, and you would tell the compiler to create the code for you using a flag...

```
tsc --module commonjs Alerts.ts
```

Comment: On a side note - I wrote about the "Common" namespace problem here in more detail back in March: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201203/Blog/Common-Is-Not-A-Name-For-An-Assembly/

Comment: Why should you use module loaders when browser is pretty capable of loading JavaScript already?

Comment: Module loaders are just one option. Bundling is more common in the browser - one big hit up front and then cached. Module loaders let you take smaller hits that don't affect page load with individual scripts being cached.

Answer (score 4):

There sure is. I wouldn't recommend it but what you're looking for is the `with` statement:

```
module Admin.MyAccount.Access {
    export function ajaxDone(data: string, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) {       
        with (Admin.Shared.Alerts) {
            alerts.mvcOnFailure("x");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I would rather use the solution provided by @Richard in his comment on your question.